# Cassandra connection pooling in Django

Tags: python, django, cassandra, connection-pooling

Most of the requests to my Django application (hosted by Apache) require connecting to a Cassandra keyspace and fetching/processing data. Currently, I open a new connection per request, which adds a 2.5s overhead to even the simplest requests!

The solution is to use connection pooling, but it's not very clear to me how this can be done in Django? Here is what I've found so far:

1. I can use an object mapper like [CQL-Engine](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/2.5/api/index.html) or [Django Cassandra Engine](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine), which they persist the connection across multiple requests. I don't need an object mapper, so I would rather skip using a library that I don't need. Of course, I'm already using Datastax Python driver, which means I could use CQL-Engine, but it's not very clear how it can help!
2. I can modify my WSGI and connect to Cassandra after the process fork, and share that with every request handled by that process (more details [here](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/python-driver-user/XuSjjWVnE9Y)). I'm currently using `mod_wsgi`, but I found more results on `gunicorn` (I don't mind switching). For `gunicorn` there is a callback, `post_fork` which I could use (as shown in [this example](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py#L180)). There I can connect, but I'm not sure how to share the connection with the application! And there is 0 example.
3. I found out if I connect to my database in my `wsgi.py` after the application is created, I can share that with my application (it works with `mod_wsgi` as well). All I had to do was something like this:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

from myapp import keyspace_manager
from django.conf import settings
cluster, session = keyspace_manager.initCassandraConnection()
settings.CLUSTER = cluster
settings.SESSION = session
```

And then I could access the cluster/session object in my request without initializing it every time.

Now my question is: is this approach (#3, init connection in `wsgi.py`), correct? What might go wrong with this?
If not, how I can do Cassandra connection pooling in Django?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: When using mod_wsgi it is more typical to have multithreaded processes and more than one request happening at the same time in the process. If that session is meant to only be used by one request at a time you will have issues.